# Уведомления на Андроид c javascript приложения

Tags: javascript, java, android

Есть приложение на `javascript`. С помощью `Android SDK` будет обернуто в `webView` чтобы была возможность сделать `apk`.

Вопрос:

Есть ли возможность хранить данные, введенные пользователем в форму в локальном хранилище, и есть ли возможность на основании этих данных показывать уведомления на телефоне?

Comment: Есть, но придется писать нативный Java/Kotlin код.

Comment: Я рекомендую попробовать вот этот путь, если возможно: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39489851/5479247